# Indirect command in subordinate clause

Tags: subordinate-clause

Consider the indirect command "He ordered them to do it," translated as *Imperavit eis ut id facerent.* The subordinate verb is in the imperfect subjunctive because the main verb is perfect.

Now if I want to use this clause in the indirect question "I don't know whether he ordered them to do it," which of these should I use:

- *Nescio num imperaverit eis ut id **facerent*** (sequence determined by verb to which it is immediately subordinate, which is perfect (albeit subjunctive))
- *Nescio num imperaverit eis ut id **faciant*** (sequence determined by main verb, which is present)

Which is correct? The answers to [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/choosing-conjunctive-tenses-in-a-clause-subordinate-to-a-subordinate-clause) suggest the first (*facerent*) is correct. I think the difficulty here is that I don't usually see the sequence being determined by the tense of a verb that is in the subjunctive, since it doesn't indicate absolute time.

Comment: In my view, this question is a duplicate, because the linked question gives the answer and also explains the logic for the shifting sequence.

Comment: Closing for now as a duplicate. We can re-open this if we get additional clarification on how the other question doesn't answer this one.